# UILabel rounded corners turn out sharp in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel, ios7.1

Since the update to iOS7.1 the UILabels in my app have changed appearance. **Prior to the OS update, all my UILabels had rounded corners as was my intention. With iOS7.1 they now all have sharp corners.**

I insert the code I use below. Any help on how to restore the UILabels to my original appearance will be appreciated.

---

Top of the implementation file of the view controller:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

---

The code for the creation of the UILabel. I have marked (what I consider) the relevant line with a comment.

```
    CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 100);

    NSString *theText = [self info];
    CGSize size = [theText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelRect.size.width, 10000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    UILabel *theLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
    [theLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [theLabel setText:theText];
    [[theLabel layer] setCornerRadius:15]; // THIS IS THE RELEVANT LINE

    // For iOS7
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
        [theLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [[self view] addSubview:theLabel];
```

Comment: Try to set label's property `clipsToBounds` to `YES`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set `theLabel.clipsToBounds = YES`, or `theLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES`. Either will work.

Comment: Only tried `[[theLabel layer] setMasksToBounds:YES]`, but it worked just as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 100);

NSString *theText = [self info];
CGSize size = [theText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelRect.size.width, 10000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

UILabel *theLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
[theLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[theLabel setText:theText];
[[theLabel layer] setCornerRadius:15]; // THIS IS THE RELEVANT LINE
[theLabel.layer setMasksToBounds:YES]; ///missing in your code
// For iOS7
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
    [theLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[[self view] addSubview:theLabel];
```